# How to improve replaceWith performance on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am rendering an array of data in table element, the data can be filtered so the table should be updated with the new data.
I am using JQuery replaceWith() for replacing the old tbody element with new tbody which represents the new data, but it seems to take very long time on IE11 to be rendered when the length of the array of data is 1700.

This is my code:

```
var markup='', table = [] // 2D array of data;
   markup += '<tbody>';
     for (var row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
       markup += '<tr role="row">';
        for (var col = 0; col < table[0].length; col++) {
                    markup += '<td>' + table[row][col] + '</td>';
         }
         markup += '</tr>';
     }
    markup += '</tbody>';

.$('#data-results > tbody').replaceWith(markup);
```

Comment: ask yourself if you really need to render all those 1700 rows

Comment: I have filters drop-down, where the user can use to filter the data in the table.
When the user select a filter, I send Ajax request to the back-end to get the new data, so I need to render all those 1700 rows again.

Comment: read about virtual table concept

Comment: @SMH But if you have all data, then do filtering in client side by `display: none` on certain row

Comment: I don't have all the data, I send user selected filter to the back-end where the Java class filter the data and send it back, however the issue is when it's come to replace the old tbody element with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, adding large strings of tags using **.append()** or **.html()** is supposed to be more efficient than adding through **.replaceWith()**. 
So, try my below lines of code to achieve the same you asked.

```
$('#data-results > tbody').empty();
$('#data-results > tbody').html(markup);
```

In otherway, you can also try **.innerHTML**

```
$('#data-results > tbody').empty();
$('#data-results > tbody').innerHTML = markup;
```